# Ext GWT vs GWT-EXT

Tags: gwt, smartgwt, gwt-ext, gxt

is there a difference between Ext GWT and GWT-Ext? Cos i was surfing Ext GWT and saw this page http://gwt-ext.com/demo/. any help guys?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

ExtGWT is marketed and maintained by the same guys who developed ExtJs library. ExtGWT shares its look and feel and API structure with ExtJS. Contrary to popular perception, ExtGWT is not  a wrapper around ExtJS javascript, but written ground up using GWT DOM and other low level GWT API's. It is 99% java based and uses no (or very little) JSNI to get things done. It also supports data binding. This library is actively supported and also has a paid commercial version.

On the other hand GWT Ext was developed by Sanjeev Jeevan as a wrapper around LGPL version (no support now) of ExtJS. So the library is a very shallow wrapper around ExtJS javascript and uses JSNI extensively. This can create problems, particularly if you need to debug the library. GWT Ext does not enjoy the same level of community support as ExtGWT and also the original author has long since moved on to a different project.

If you have to choose between the two, and plain old GWT is not an option, choose ExtGWT. Keep in mind that it is GNU GPL licensed.

Comment: +1 Very nice answer - I've always wondered what's the difference (and if there's any difference at all) between those two.

Answer (score 0):

Neither. You'll have nothing, but problems with third-party GWT widget libraries. I've wasted four years on significantly more refined and mature SmartGWT and finally gave up.

Styling standard GWT components that wrap native browser controls is easy. You should strive for native portable control set and you'll rarely need anything more for a modern minimalistic mobile-friendly UX. However if you still crave some third-party widgets, look at GWT-Bootstrap3: https://github.com/gwtbootstrap3/gwtbootstrap3