# Hello World in  GWT EXT(GXT)

Tags: gxt

i want to start with Gwt ext , just trying to write my first program (Hello World) in EXT-GWT from this [tutorial](http://www.sencha.com/learn/setting-up-your-first-ext-gwt-project-in-eclipse/)

But when i run my program it says

> unable to find 'com/extjs/gxt/ui/GXT.gwt.xml' on your classpath;

if i then replace it in my xml file to

```
<inherits name='com.gwtext.GwtExt'/>
```

then it gives this error

> com.google.gwt.core.client.JavaScriptException: (TypeError): '$wnd.Ext' is  null or not an object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you trying to get stared with GWT Ext, using a tutorial for Ext GWT? In this case, order is important, GWT Ext is different from Ext GWT.

Having that said, and assuming you want to get started with ExtGwt, not GWT EXT, you probably don't have the EXTGwt jar in your classpath.

Also, in the tutorial it says you should have this:

```
<inherits name="com.extjs.gxt.ui.GXT" />
```

in your gwt.xml file. Don't change it to GwtExt, because like I said before, ExtGWT != GWT Ext.

Difference is:

ExtGWT is the product this category on StackOverflow reffers to. It's developed by sencha.

GWT Ext is an open source wrapper for ExtJS (developed by Sencha also).

See this post for a more clear view: http://roberthanson.blogspot.com/2008/04/gwt-ext-vs-ext-gwt.html, or this one: [Difference between gwt-ext and ext-gwt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1161029/difference-between-gwt-ext-and-ext-gwt)